# show results from two splunk queries into one

Tags: join, splunk

I have two separate splunk queries:
1st Query : Outputs unique user count in last 24 hours
2nd Query : Outputs unique users count in last 24 hours in geo = US

I want to create a timechart that will show , a line chart with % of user everyday from US.

How can this be achieved.

Answer (score 5):

You can join the two queries by using :

`|`

So your query can look like this:

```
{firstQuery} as countUS| {secondQuery} as countTotal | eval perc=countUS/countTotal
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a conditional to count those from US

Example query:

```
index=data | timechart dc(user) as dc_user, dc(eval(if(geo=US,user,NULL))) as us_user | eval perc_us=round(us_user/dc_user*100,2) | table _time, perc_us
```

Alternatively you can use the SPL join command but that would be less efficient as it would have to read the data twice and join the results.

Answer (score 0):

Can you anonymize your data, and show the query here? There's lots of ways to do this in Splunk, but we will need a bit more to go on.

for example

```
Query: index=myindex sourcetype=mySourcetype | stats count dc(ip) as userTotal | append [ index=myindex sourcetype=mySourcetype region=US | stats dc(ip) as USTotal]
```

Comment: I was thinking append as well.  You should probably say "for example, you could use append:" or something similar so it is obvious what your example is an example of - the reason I suggest this is that the word "append" in the preformatted text doesn't show up on my screen - I have to actually scroll to the right to see it.